# convert function return from ‘std::vector<QString>’ to ‘QVariant’

Tags: qt, stdvector, qvariant

I am working on a QT based application.One of of my class is a child class of [QAbstractTableModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QAbstractTableModel.html). The data function has a return type of [QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QVariant.html)(Union).But i want to return a custom type `std::vector<QString>`

Came to know about [`Q_DECLARE_METATYPE();`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE) It makes new types available to QVariant.

-Test Case Code-

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMetaType>
#include <vector>
#include<QVariant>


Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(std::vector<QString>);

QVariant data(int role)
{
    std::vector<QString> test1;   
    test1.push_back("Dtd");
    test1.push_back("Dtd"); 
    return test1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
     data(1);    
    return app.exec();
}
```

I am getting this error

> error: could not convert ‘test1’ from ‘std::vector< QString >’ to ‘QVariant’

I am missing out something.Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you've declared a new metatype, the compiler still sees you're trying to return a `std::vector` where you've declared returning a QVariant. Try this:

```
QVariant data(int role)
{
    std::vector<QString> test1;   
    test1.push_back("Dtd");
    test1.push_back("Dtd");
    QVariant var;
    var.setValue(test1); 
    return var;
}
```