# convert a std vector <int> to QVariant

Tags: qt, casting, stdvector, qmetatype

I would like to be able to convert a std string to a QVariant.

```
#include<vector>
#include <QMetaType>   

using namespace std;
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(vector<int>)
int main()
{ 
vector <int> blabla;
QVariant wanted=QVariant(blabla)
}
```

> no matching function for call to
>   'QVariant::QVariant(std::vector&)'
>        QVariant organsizes=QVariant(this->organsizes);

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert function return from ‘std::vector<QString>’ to ‘QVariant’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9805023/convert-function-return-from-stdvectorqstring-to-qvariant)

Comment: `std vector <int>` or   `std string` .. correct yourself.